# Segmentation Fault occuring while assigning values of array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to set array's length according as a file's line number. I declared my arrays in main function and passed to setMatrix.

main function

```
    int x;
    x=numberOfId();
    int graph[x][x];
    int path[x];
    char *pathString[x];
    setMatrix(graph,path,pathString,x);
```

setMatrix function

```
void setMatrix(int **graph,int *path,char **pathString,int k){
    int i,j;    
for(i=1;i<k;i++){ 
    for(j=1;j<k;j++){
        graph[i][j]=INFINITY;//I get error here
    }
}
```

I'm sure I did an easy mistake but couldn't see.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are not the same thing as pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Don't try to use multidimensional arrays in place of multiple indirection?

Comment: `void setMatrix(int **graph,int *path,char **pathString,int k){` --> `void setMatrix(int k, int graph[k][k]/* or int graph[][k] or int (*graph)[k] */, int *path, char **pathString){`

Comment: This one worked, @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function definition should match the arrays:

```
void setMatrix(int x, int graph[x][x], int path[x], char *pathString[x])
{
```

The `int x` has to be first so that it is in scope for the later parameters.  It is possible to use pointer notation instead of the innermost array bound, but it serves as self-documentation to use the array notation.

Arrays and pointers are different; `int **` is not the same as `int[x][x]`.